# server to server real-time communiation

Tags: php, apache, drupal, p2p

I have two LAMP (using Drupal CMS) based websites and I want to perform communication between the servers. As an example, a client on website 1 performs some activity, the data and content is communicated to website 2 , website 2 process the data /request and responds back to the website 1 client. How can I do this ? Are there any libraries or modules to achieve this?  Where do I start to build such a feature?

Comment: sounds like you want to write an api.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, can be done with sockets through the HTTP protocol using POST query.

For instance, there is a communication from the server A, to the server B. notice : you can make it bidirectional.

**HTTP QUERY (client)**

```
# the target url (without http://) or address of the remote host
# if the remote address is an ipv6 she must start and end with [] like this [::1].
$http_host = "website1.com"; # api.website1.com or localhost or 13.33.33.37

# The address of the script who's give answer from the root directory "/".
$script_path = "/answer.php";

# The parameters.
$http_params = "cost=156&product=" . urlencode("string must be url encoded");

$http_query  = "POST " . $script_path . " HTTP/1.0" . "\r\n";
$http_query .= "Host: " . $http_host . "\r\n";
$http_query .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" . "\r\n";
$http_query .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($http_params) . "\r\n";
$http_query .= "User-Agent: Drupal/PHP" . "\r\n\r\n";
$http_query .= $http_params;

$http_answer = NULL;

if ($socket = @fsockopen($http_host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10))
{
    fwrite($socket, $http_query);

    while (!feof($socket))
        $http_answer .= fgets($socket, 1024);

    fclose($socket);
}

$http_answer = explode("\r\n", $http_answer);

if (is_array($http_answer))
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($http_answer);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

With a bit of imagination, you can build pretty nice tools: Google themselve use this way to generate challenges on reCAPTCHA.

**HTTP HANDLER (server)**

```
# if the parameters are matched.
if (isset($_POST['cost'], $_POST['product']))
{
    # some treatement on the data
    if (is_numeric($_POST['cost']))
        echo "The cost were defined to $_POST[cost]" . "\r\n";
    else
        echo "The cost attribute must be a numerical value." . "\r\n";

    if (!is_numeric($_POST['product']))
        echo "The product were correctly registered." . "\r\n";
    else
        echo "The product attribute must be different than a numerical value." . "\r\n";
}

# otherwise the parameters are wrong.
else echo "Something went wrong.";
```